# Flutter: The method '[ ]' was called on null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am getting the following error for the following code.
https://github.com/Avi-nash5/CP-flutter-app/blob/master/lib/PlatformScreen.dart
the error screen is shown for 1 sec then it loads as it is supposed to do. please help.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY97L.jpg)
[how it is supposed to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRAAR.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the relevant code that is responsible for the error instead of the whole file as its harder to debug without running the code. The error might be with `data[index]['name']` as you are calling it in `Text` widget and it might be null at the start so you need to perform a null check.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste `PlatformScreen` in full code 
`data` is not ready when use 
You can use a bool `_isLoading` to control, if `data` is not ready show `CircularProgressIndicator`

```
bool _isLoading = true;
...
Future<String> getJsonData() async {
    ...
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
... 
child: _isLoading
      ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.white,))
      : ListView.builder(
```

working demo

[image]

full code of `PlatformScreen`

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'PlatformModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class PlatformScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Platform platform;

  PlatformScreen({this.platform});

  @override
  PlatformScreenState createState() => PlatformScreenState();
}

class PlatformScreenState extends State<PlatformScreen> {
  List data;
  int n;
  bool _isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
      getJsonData();
    });
  }

  Future<String> getJsonData() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(widget.platform.url),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    print(response.body);

    data = jsonDecode(response.body);

    n = data.length;
    print(data);
    convert();
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
    return "Success";
  }

  void convert() {
    print(n);
    var now = new DateTime.now();
    now = now.toLocal();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      var start = DateTime.parse(data[i]['start_time']);
      var end = DateTime.parse(data[i]['end_time']);
      start = start.toLocal();
      end = end.toLocal();
      data[i]['start_time'] = start.toString();
      data[i]['end_time'] = end.toString();
    }
    print(data);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 25.0,
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      height: 125,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Hero(
                            tag: widget.platform.imgurl,
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                              child: Image(
                                height: 125,
                                width: 125,
                                image: AssetImage(widget.platform.imgurl),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(125, 0, 0, 0),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  widget.platform.name,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 32,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      ),
                      child: _isLoading
                          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.white,))
                          : ListView.builder(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                              itemCount: n,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                      15.0, 15.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 150,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                        borderRadius:
                                            BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                        boxShadow: [
                                          BoxShadow(
                                            color: Colors.black54,
                                            offset: Offset(0, 10.0),
                                            blurRadius: 10.0,
                                          )
                                        ]),
                                    child: Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                            data[index]['name'],
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 18,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```